# Cor do texto em QTableView

Tags: c++

Olá, estou tentando implementar a cor do texto em determinada coluna do meu QTableView, sem sucesso

para pintar a célula, basta usar o código abaixo no meu delegate que funciona:

```
painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor(255, 40, 0));
```

Para mudar a cor do texto estava tentando:

```
painter->setPen(Qt::red);
```

mas não funcionou.

Alguém poderia me dar uma ajuda?

obrigado, Juliano.

Comment: Dependendo do que quiser fazer, é muito mais prático reimplementar isso aqui: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data - aí você simplesmente vai retornar o que quiser, de acordo com o _role_. Se o _role_ for texto, pode retornar o valor. Se o _role_ for cor de frente ou de fundo, retorne a cor/textura que quiser. Se não retornar nada customizado, ele usa o _default_.